# Drawing a snowman in ASCII art

Tags: beginner, go, ascii-art

I am learning Go and as an exercise I did [this challenge from Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49671) (without the golfing), where an ASCII art snowman is drawn from a combination of body parts, based on an 8-digit code taken as command line argument.

For example:

```
$ ./snowman 12431312

 _===_ 
 (-.O) 
<( : )\
 ( : )
```

As a minor extension I decided to use a random code if none is passed.

Coming from Python, I had hoped to use the static typing to my advantage (e. g. by checking at compile time that the definition of body parts is valid), but I have the feeling that I am fighting it more than it helps me.

I'd like to know how I can make the code less verbose and repetitive, and how I can use the static typing to make the code less error-prone and brittle.

#### snowman.go

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Snowman [5][7]rune

func (s Snowman) getLine(i int) string {
    var line string
    for _, c := range s[i] {
        line += string(c)
    }
    return line
}

func (s Snowman) String() string {
    var result string
    for i := range s {
        if i > 0 {
            result += "\n"
        }
        result += s.getLine(i)
    }
    return result
}

type Hat [2][5]rune
type Nose rune
type Eye rune
type LeftArm [2]rune
type RightArm [2]rune
type Torso [3]rune
type Base [3]rune

var hats = [...]Hat{
    {{' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '}, {'_', '=', '=', '=', '_'}},
    {{' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '}, {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}},
    {{' ', ' ', '_', ' ', ' '}, {' ', '/', '_', '\\', ' '}},
    {{' ', '_', '_', '_', ' '}, {'(', '_', '*', '_', ')'}},
}

var noses = [...]Nose{',', '.', '_', ' '}

var eyes = [...]Eye{'.', 'o', 'O', '-'}

var leftArms = [...]LeftArm{{' ', '<'}, {'\\', ' '}, {' ', '/'}, {' ', ' '}}

var rightArms = [...]RightArm{{' ', '>'}, {'/', ' '}, {' ', '\\'}, {' ', ' '}}

var torsos = [...]Torso{
    {' ', ':', ' '},
    {']', ' ', '['},
    {'>', ' ', '<'},
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
}

var bases = [...]Base{
    {' ', ':', ' '},
    {'"', ' ', '"'},
    {'_', '_', '_'},
    {' ', ' ', ' '},
}

// newSnowman returns a Snowman with no hat, arms, face, torso, or base.
func newSnowman() Snowman {
    var s Snowman
    for _, i := range [3]int{0, 1, 4} {
        s[i][0] = ' '
        s[i][6] = ' '
    }
    for i := 2; i < 5; i++ {
        s[i][1] = '('
        s[i][5] = ')'
    }
    return s
}

func (s *Snowman) setHat(h Hat) {
    for i, line := range h {
        for j, c := range line {
            s[i][j+1] = c
        }
    }
}

func (s *Snowman) setNose(n Nose) {
    s[2][3] = rune(n)
}

func (s *Snowman) setLeftEye(e Eye) {
    s[2][2] = rune(e)
}

func (s *Snowman) setRightEye(e Eye) {
    s[2][4] = rune(e)
}

func (s *Snowman) setLeftArm(a LeftArm) {
    for i, c := range a {
        s[i+2][0] = c
    }
}

func (s *Snowman) setRightArm(a RightArm) {
    for i, c := range a {
        s[i+2][6] = c
    }
}

func (s *Snowman) setTorso(t Torso) {
    for i, c := range t {
        s[3][i+2] = c
    }
}

func (s *Snowman) setBase(b Base) {
    for i, c := range b {
        s[4][i+2] = c
    }
}

type SnowmanCode [8]int

func snowmanCodeFromString(s string) (SnowmanCode, error) {
    var result SnowmanCode
    if len(s) != 8 {
        return result, errors.New("expected 8 digits")
    }
    for i, digit := range s {
        num, err := strconv.Atoi(string(digit))
        if err != nil {
            return result, err
        }
        result[i] = num
    }
    return result, nil
}

func randomCode() SnowmanCode {
    return SnowmanCode{
        rand.Intn(len(hats)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(noses)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(eyes)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(eyes)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(leftArms)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(rightArms)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(torsos)) + 1,
        rand.Intn(len(bases)) + 1,
    }
}

func SnowmanFromCode(c SnowmanCode) (Snowman, error) {
    s := newSnowman()
    if !(1 <= c[0] && c[0] <= len(hats)) {
        return s, errors.New("hat code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[1] && c[1] <= len(noses)) {
        return s, errors.New("nose code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[2] && c[2] <= len(eyes)) {
        return s, errors.New("left eye code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[3] && c[3] <= len(eyes)) {
        return s, errors.New("right eye code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[4] && c[4] <= len(leftArms)) {
        return s, errors.New("left arm code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[5] && c[5] <= len(rightArms)) {
        return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[6] && c[6] <= len(torsos)) {
        return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
    }
    if !(1 <= c[7] && c[7] <= len(bases)) {
        return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
    }
    s.setHat(hats[c[0]-1])
    s.setNose(noses[c[1]-1])
    s.setLeftEye(eyes[c[2]-1])
    s.setRightEye(eyes[c[3]-1])
    s.setLeftArm(leftArms[c[4]-1])
    s.setRightArm(rightArms[c[5]-1])
    s.setTorso(torsos[c[6]-1])
    s.setBase(bases[c[7]-1])
    return s, nil
}

func codeFromArgsOrRandom() (SnowmanCode, error) {
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        return snowmanCodeFromString(os.Args[1])
    } else {
        return randomCode(), nil
    }
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    code, err := codeFromArgsOrRandom()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    s, err := SnowmanFromCode(code)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Cute project ;-)

---

Do you see where copy-paste coding got the better of you?

> ```
> if !(1 <= c[5] && c[5] <= len(rightArms)) {
>     return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
> }
> if !(1 <= c[6] && c[6] <= len(torsos)) {
>     return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
> }
> if !(1 <= c[7] && c[7] <= len(bases)) {
>     return s, errors.New("right arm code out of range")
> }
> ```

I meant the mocking jab at "copy-paste coding" is a joke.
While in the above it may be possible to extract common elements and generalize the logic, that would be a slippery slope to over-engineering.
And in any case, in Go, as far as I know, simple code with duplicated logic is preferred over complicated code.

---

I think you could eliminate `getLine` by converting the rune array to a string with `string(line[:])`:

```
func (s Snowman) String() string {
    var result string
    for i, line := range s {
        if i > 0 {
            result += "\n"
        }
        result += string(line[:])
    }
    return result
}
```

Of course this simplification with `line[:]` comes at the price of allocating a new slice. But given the scale of the task at hand, I think that's a reasonable compromise.